# In what situations Static Allocation fares better than Dynamic Allocation?

Tags: memory, memory-management

I was going through some of the decisions made to make [Xara Xtreme](http://www.xaraxtreme.org/), an open source SVG graphics application. Their memory management decision was quite intriguing to me since I naively took it for granted that on-demand dynamic allocation as the way of writing object oriented application.

The explanation from the documentation is

> > How on earth can static allocations be efficient?
> >
> > If you are used to large dynamic data structures, this may seem strange
> >     to you. Firstly, all our objects (and
> >     thus allocation size) are far smaller
> >     (on average) than each dynamic area
> >     allocation within a program such as
> >     Impression. This means that though
> >     there are likely to be many holes
> >     within memory, they are small. Also,
> >     we have far more allocated objects
> >     within memory, and thus these holes
> >     quickly get filled. Furthermore,
> >     virtual memory managers will free up
> >     any pages of memory that contain no
> >     allocations and give this memory back
> >     to the operating system so that it may
> >     be used again (either by us, or by
> >     another task).
> >
> > We benefit greatly from
> >     the fact that whenever we allocate
> >     memory in this manner, we do not have
> >     to move any memory about. This proved
> >     a bottleneck in ArtWorks which also
> >     had many small allocations being used
> >     concurrently. [more](http://www.xaraxtreme.org/Developers/camelot-technical-basics.html#ObjectsMemoryManagement)

In brief, the presence of plenty of small objects and the need to prevent memory move are the reasons given for choosing static allocation. I don't have clear understanding about the reasons mentioned.

Though this talks about static allocation, what I see from the cursory look at the code is that a block of memory is dynamically allocated at the application start and kept alive till the application ends, roughly simulating static allocation.

Could you explain in what situations Static Allocation fares better than on-demand Dynamic Allocation in order to consider it as the main mode of allocation in a serious applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quicker because you avoid the overhead of calling a system routine to manage your storage.  `malloc()` maintains a heap, so every request requires a scan for an appropriately-sized block, possibly resizing the block, updating the block list to mark this block as used, etc.  If you're allocating a lot of small objects, this overhead can be excessive.  With static allocation you can create an allocation pool and just maintain a simple bitmap to show which areas are in use.  This assumes that each object is the same size, so you commonly create one pool per object type.

Comment: Thank you. I now see that object pool pattern is the technique used in Xara Xtreme. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern

Answer (score 1):

In short, there's really no such thing as static allocation other than the space allocated for your functions themselves and other read-only kinds of memory. (Do an assemble-only "gcc -S" and look for all the memory blocks, if you're interested.) If you're making and breaking objects, you're dynamically allocating. That being said, there's nothing to stop you from tightly controlling the allocation mechanism itself.

That's what functions like mallinfo() and mallopt() do for controlling how malloc() does its magic. However, that might not even be good enough for you. If you know all your chunks are going to be the same size, you can allocate and deallocate much more efficiently. And if you know you have 3 sizes of stuff, you can keep 3 arenas of memory each with their own allocator.

On top of this, you have the situation at runtime where the process doesn't have enough room and needs to ask the os for more - that involves a system call that is more expensive than just incrementing an array index. On unix, it's usually brk() or sbrk() or the like. And that can take valuable time.

Another, rarer situation, would be if you need to multiply-allocate things. Like 3 threads need to share information and only when all 3 release it does it get freed. That's something nonstandard and not generally covered by typical mallopt() or even pthread-specific memory or mutex/semaphore-locked chunks.

So if you have high speed optimization issues or you are running on an embedded system where you need to squeeze all you can out of the available memory, then "static allocation", or at least controlling the allocation mechanism, may be the way to go.